Cyrillic font in DND-5e-LaTeX-Template
When using Cyrillic characters, they are not displayed, and in the output it says that the character was not found in the lmroman9-regular font. This does not work only in special environments like DndComment or DndMonster. I don't know how to solve this problem.
Here is a part of the latex output:
Missing character: There is no К (U+041A) in font [lmroman9-regular]:+tlig;!
На русском:
При использовании кириллических символов в DND-5e-LaTeX-Template (класс для написания историй для DnD) они не выводятся и появляется ошибка "символ не найден в lmroman9-regular". Я пытался решить эту проблему, но у меня не получилось. Что я могу сделать?
Example code:
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,twocolumn,openany,nodeprecatedcode]{dndbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\usepackage[main=russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{DndComment}{Какой-нибудь абстрактный текст}
  Какой-нибудь абстрактый текст.
\end{DndComment}
\end{document}

Resultat:

Engine: Luatex

Welcome to TeX.SE.  Can you create a ~10 line sample that shows your problem without us needing to visit other sites?  That usually works much better than trying to describe the problem.  And can you leave your last paragraph in english?

Your example shows several warnings.
Missing character: There is no К (U+041A) in font [lmsans10-bold]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no а (U+0430) in font [lmsans10-bold]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no к (U+043A) in font [lmsans10-bold]:+tlig;!

There are other warnings, though:
Package multicol Warning: May not work with the twocolumn option on input line
139.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/pbk/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 116.

==> First Aid for ngerman.sty no longer applied!
    Expected:
        1998/07/08 v2.5e Support for writing german texts (br)
    but found:

    so I'm assuming it got fixed.

The last one is due to a name conflict: the LaTeX kernel is aware that ngerman.sty (the one distributed with TeX Live or MiKTeX) is obsolete and takes precautions not to load it, but it realizes that the ngerman.sty file distributed with the template is a different animal. I'd recommend the authors of the template to avoid names of files already present in the main distributions.
The multicol warning is due to the fact that the option twocolumn doesn't disable loading multicol, which it should do.
The font warning is due to a mysterious usage by the class of `bookman.sty, I don't understand the reason for.
My impression is that the class wants to do too much.
Anyway, the main problem is that you must load some font that supports Cyrillic, which the default Latin Modern font doesn't.
This can be fixed by looking at the last unmentioned warnings:
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmss/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmss/bx/n' instead on input line 9.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/GilliusADFNoTwo-LF/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 9.

Inside DndComment the Gillius font is selected. This can be disabled by passing the layout=false option, but you have to set a sans serif font.
\documentclass[10pt,layout=false,twoside,twocolumn,openany,nodeprecatedcode]{dndbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Sans}

\usepackage[main=russian, english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{DndComment}{Какой-нибудь абстрактный текст}
  Какой-нибудь абстрактый текст.
\end{DndComment}
\end{document}


Complain with the developers about the scanty documentation.

From those error messages, it would also be possible to set up \newfontfamily\gillius{GilliusADFNo2}[NFSSFamily=GilliusADFNoTwo-LF] to get Gillius working again. However, the font still wouldn’t have Cyrillic letters.
